# Convert multiple input value to json array on Php?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to convert multiple input values to json array using php.

Form:

```
<input name="title[]">
<input name="description[]">
<input name="total[]">
```

What i'm trying to get:

```
{"results":
 [{"title", "description", "total" }],
 [{"title", "description", "total" }],
 [{"title", "description", "total" }],
 [{"title", "description", "total" }]
}
```

Php Code:

```
$itemCount = count($_POST["title"]);
$_POST['results'] = [];

for($i=0;$i<$itemCount;$i++) {
    if(!empty($_POST["title"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["description"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["total"][$i])) {
        $_POST['results'] = json_encode([
            [
                'title' => cleardata($_POST["title"][$i]),
                'description' => cleardata($_POST['description'][$i]),
                'total' => cleardata($_POST['total'][$i])
            ],
        ]);
    }
}

print_r(json_encode($_POST['results']));
```

Comment: You don't say what you are actually getting, or give an indication of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form isn’t clear. I’ll assume it is a set of inputs, each `title` matching with exactly one `description` and exactly one `total` fields.

Also, the JSON you expect is not valid.

We’re making new arrays with elements with the same index in each posted array. You can eventually cast them to Object. We combine them in a global array and parse it to JSON thanks to [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php).

```
// Since you didn’t indicate form method
$titleData = $_POST['title'] ?? $_GET['title'];
$descriptionData = $_POST['description'] ?? $_GET['description'];
$totalData = $_POST['total'] ?? $_GET['total'];

$results = [];

foreach ($titleData as $count => $result) {
    $results[] = [$result, $descriptionData[$count], $totalData[$count]];
    // You may cast the added array with (object) if you expect an object
    // rather than an array.
}

return json_encode( ["results" => $results] );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have question what i have to do in case i want that the tille should not be repeated inside foreach, for example will be as a header like {"title": "value", "description": "value", "total": "value"}, {"description": "value", "total": "value"}

Comment: In this case, I would instantiate the first row before the loop: `$results[] = ['title' => $titleData[0], 'description' => $descriptionData[0], 'total' => $totalData[0]];` and I would use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` to start with the second row:
`for ($count=1; $count < count($totalData); $count++) { $results[] = ['description' => $descriptionData[$count], 'total' => $totalData[$count]]; }`